# Sync the local HTML5 Database with MongoDB

Tags: html, mongodb, indexeddb

What is the best strategy to synchronize the local database with the server one?

The idea is to use a 100% HTML5 application, so every morning, the server database will be duplicated to clients, so the clients will only work on IndexedDB, untill the end of the day, where the clients will send all the data to the server, and then the server will gather them and save them again, but as you can see, it is a lot of work, so is there a better way the IndexedDB or MongoDB offer to connect to each other?

Comment: This is something i've been looking to do with mongo for a couple of years now. Mongo is not designed to be a sync-able db unlike it's cousin couchdb. I actually ended up writing a complex wrapper for mongodb

Comment: Basically: Is there a PouchDB for MongoDB correct?

Answer (score 0):

If all your logics are in client, you don't need MongoDB. Just key-value store with REST API and collection query by last-modified is good enough.

I had [a sample sync app](https://github.com/yathit/feature-matrix) with Google cloud storage.

Comment: yes, but at the end of the day, everything must be synchronized on one database, it will use tornado and mongodb, so the application will have two interfaces and will be easier to manage (like the old-school app where they make on client and one for the admin).